# Get filename path from test/resources in junit test

Tags: java, file, testing, junit, filenames

I want to read a Junit Test for my CsvReader Adapter. It takes filename as argument in constructor. I have placed a file test.txt in src/test/resources for testing purposes, however I can't figure out how to get to this file from test. When I just pass the filename I get FileNotFoundException.
I've read about method with class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name), however I can't pass InputStream instead of filename to constructor, because I need to reopen file several times to get back to the beginning of file after reading it whole. Unfortunately third-party CSVReaders don't take RandomAccessFile as argument and I didn't invent any better solution. So it there always working method to get path to test/resources/file.txt from Junit Test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At runtime, that file doesn't live in test/resources.  Your build system/IDE will have put it *inside* a Jar, or somewhere in your classes/ directory.  Either way, it will only be accessible via the classpath; `getResourceAsStream()` abstracts that away, so that's what you should be using.

If you *really* need a filename (i.e. if that's an unavoidable aspect of how your class works<sup>*</sup>), then you should consider using JUnit's [`@TemporaryFolder` rule](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/junit-creating-temporary-files-using.html); have your test setup copy the contents of the resource file into a temporary file, and then pass the name of that to your constructor.

---

<sub>* And that sounds like a design flaw, you should consider rewriting your class to work with abstractions.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question and had an answer, but I understand when you want to work with a file path especially when working in JUnit that normally isn't packaged and delivered to the user.

As such here's my way of getting the path for JUnit using Java 8.

```
 URL resource = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Name_of_file.csv");
 File file = Paths.get(res.toURI()).toFile();
 String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
```